# Which stage is when I re-enter into the app from home screen

Tags: ios, swift

I want to change some thing when I re-enter into my app, but I don't know where I should put those changes in, I tried to search and found viewdidappear would be a solution, but it's not correct

Answer (score 2, accepted):

U can used `UIApplicationWillEnterForegroundNotification` to notify your app that your are return from background.

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self, selector: "EnterForgroundState", name: UIApplicationWillEnterForegroundNotification, object: nil)
}

func EnterForgroundState(){
      // do your work
    }
```

Answer (score 6):

You can use `applicationDidBecomeActive:` in your `UIApplicationDelegate`.

[Documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIApplicationDelegate_Protocol/#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/UIApplicationDelegate/applicationDidBecomeActive:)

Comment: I'm now confused about how can I change the text in my viewcontroller from my delegate?

Answer (score 1):

as @snowman pointed out
You need to find these methods in your App Delegate.m files which means the following

1.`application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions` - Application launches from terminated status

2.`applicationWillResignActive:(UIApplication *)application` - Application becomes active from terminated/ background status

3.`applicationDidEnterBackground:(UIApplication *)application` -  Application did enter a background state, from an active state.

4.`applicationDidBecomeActive:(UIApplication *)application` - Application is in an active state (this method is hit once it is fully active.)

5.`applicationWillTerminate:(UIApplication *)application` - Application is about to be terminated.

As these methods are in App delegate which means these methods will respond to states or callbacks from your application.
For more understanding put breakpoints in each of these methods or put a log and play with your simulator a bit by changing its state.

Answer (score 0):

When you close the app the application enters background and again if you reopen means it will call this method applicationWillEnterForeground. so, you can write logic here.